# Image color saturation

Tags: image, image-processing

I was trying to find a functional form for saturation but didn't find anything. It can't be that hard but all my guesses don't look quite right (the direction towards desaturation seems easier).

I have the pixel data of the image in RGB format. The final image should also be in RGB format. So, how are these functions defined:

```
r_n = saturation_r(r,g,b,sat);
g_n = saturation_g(r,g,b,sat);
b_n = saturation_b(r,g,b,sat);
```

Comment: What does the `sat` argument mean?  Are you taking a RGB color as input and then outputting the same color with the saturation changed to `sat`?  Are you looking for a function to convert RGB to HSL, or do you already know how to do that?  There's a good wikipedia entry on HSV and HSL transformations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the RGB pixel to HLS, scale the S by your `sat` input, then convert back to RGB. Pseudo-code, assuming all color components are in the range 0.0 to 1.0:

```
rgb_to_hls(r, g, b, h, l, s);
s = s * sat
hls_to_rgb(h, l, s, r, g, b);
return r, g, b
```

If you need RGB/HLS conversion functions, [here they are](http://axonflux.com/handy-rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-c).

Comment: if you cant find a conversion to HLS you can also use HSV or HSI